# Sequelize, Order By count of include?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to order by most `CategoryTopics` descending. How do i order by count of this association?

```
const query = this.query(lang, nested);

    if (count && nested) {
      query.include = [
        {
          model: this.TopicModel,
          as: 'CategoryTopics',
          attributes: ['id'],
        },
      ];

      query.order = [
        ['CategoryTopics','DESC']
      ];

    }

    const categories = (await this.CategoryModel.findAll(query)).map((el) =>
      el.get({ plain: true }),
    );
```